# Urban/Rural Indicator in SAS

Tags: sas, location, maps

I am trying to determine if a customer lives in a rural or urban county. So i was wondering  if there is a PROC formula to identify if a particular county is urban or rural using zip-code?

Thanks!

Comment: Look into PROC GEOCODE if that's an option. Not sure if it can tell if it's rural or urban but it can get the lat/long and return other useful spatial information.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find not a PROC, but a data source that links zip codes to this indicator. Once you have that data imported in SAS, you can merge it with your customer data.